# How to allow members of a group to read current and new files on a directory?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

Members of the purchasing group should be able to read all the files in /data/sales. In addition, members must be able to read new files ever created in this directory. How am I going to get this done?

I understand and can read permissions but setting them is something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- set the group for directory `/data/sales` to group `purchasing`.
- set all files in `/data/sales/` to the group `purchasing`
- set the permissions for the directory and the files to "read". The means they can not remove a file and can not change a file.

If I understood it correctly I would say ...

```
chgrp -R purchasing /data/sales
chmod 2750 /data/sales
chmod -R 0740 /data/sales/
```

- 1st one: set all files and dirs to group `purchasing`
- 2nd one does the dir itself
- the 2 means files in the dir will be created with the group permissions
- 3rd one does the files inside the dir
- the -R does all files inside /data/sales/
- the 7 is read, write, execute for the owner
- the 5 means read and execute for the group. Users in the group can not delete and can not create new files. This applies to new files too.
- the 4 is read for group. So the group can view files, not alter then and not delete them.
- the 0 is no access for others

I assume owner gets full permissions and others get none. If those need to be applied too the 2nd and 4th digit in the commands need to be adjusted.

Commands also assume the one changing this has permissions to do so. If not add a `sudo` in front of the lines (or use `root`).

Comment: This helps me a lot. Can I ask you how you start troubleshooting to get this done? Do you break this down in to smaller pieces/tasks in your head before you even start?

Comment: Does this address the *"members must be able to read new files ever created in this directory"* requirement? Doesn't that also require the `setgid` bit?

Comment: @steeldriver you might be correct there. I tend to use ACL when it gets complicated >:-D Might not be able to fix that the next few minutes but will when I get home

Comment: It appears not. But I believe this can be accomplished by replacing the first digit on the left with 2.

Comment: @Moebuntu that sounds correct - or symbolically, `chmod g+s /data/sales`